# How to catch errors when printing raw text in C

Tags: c, windows, printing

I know how to simply print a text file to the printer:
(See my question below the code block)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ( void )
{
     FILE * Printer = fopen("LPT1", "w");
     FILE * FilePointer;
     char str[256];
     char buf[BUFSIZ];
     FilePointer = fopen("sample.txt", "r");
     if( !FilePointer )
     {
        printf("File does not exist\n");
        return -1;
     }
     while( fgets ( buf, sizeof buf, FilePointer ) != NULL ) 
     {
            fprintf(Printer, "%s", buf);
     }
         printf("\nPrinting..\n");
     fprintf(Printer, "\f");

     getch(); 
     return 0;
}
```

But my problem is for error catching when using this technique to print a text to printer.
What if the user has no valid or usable printer at that time? I want my program to spit out something like: "Error: printer does not exist!".

Is there anything I could do with that? Thanks!

Comment: printer is not a simple text file. You can not work like that. Try google first?

Comment: I removed the C++ tag since this is C code.

Comment: I am not sure, but have you tried controlling the returning value of fprintf? It returns a negative value if it was impossible to write, so I suppose that is what happens when there is no printer. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fprintf/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the printer is online, but **only** if you have access to kernel mode, if you are a printing driver or under Windows 95/98.

Usually, the printer port address is set `0x378` (data register of parallel port). Adding one (`0x379`) to this gives us the address of the status register of the parallel port. bit 4 of the status register (SELECT) tells us whether the printer is online or offline. if the bit is set, then the printer is online 
and if its 0, the bit is offline. 
It can look like this :

```
int status;

// get status register value at 0x379
status = _inp (0x379);

if (status & 0x10) // check bit 4
{
// printer online
}
else
{
// printer offline
}
```

Here are the other member of this register :

```
 bit 1 : DCN
 bit 3 : FAULT
 bit 4 : SELECT
 bit 5 : PAPER END
 bit 6 : ACKNOWLEDGE
 bit 7 : BUSY
```

It's coming from [codeguru](http://www.codeguru.com/Cpp/W-P/printing/article.php/c2949). But take note you should better use a higher interface like the printer api in WIN32 (OpenPrinter(), WritePrinter() StarDocPrinter(), StartPagePrinter(), etc.)

Comment: I don't believe you get access to the data-ports unless you are in kernel mode (i.e. user-level executing code can't do that)

Comment: @Jason I agree with you, see the first line of my answer

Comment: I guess when I think of "privileged user", I think of a super-user or root-type access permission, which is not the same thing as kernel-mode (i.e., a driver). In other words you can be running an executable with admin or root privileges at the OS level, but that will not change the current privileged level in the processor from user-mode to kernel-mode.